# Python, Seaborn set default style with xtick.rotation

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to set some default styles for Seaborn graphs in a Jupyter Notebook, but am failing to do so. I would expect the following to work, but as demonstrated in the picture, it has no effect. I experience the same if I try to set other parameters. The code generates no errors, but the set parameters never affect the plot. Does anybody know where I am going wrong? (I have als tried achieving the same using seaborn.set with the same (lack of) results.)

```
seaborn.set_style('ticks', {'xtick.rotation': -90})
seaborn.barplot(x='Type', y='No. people', data=pd.DataFrame({'No. people': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Type': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']}))
```

[image: Result]